# How to check if a div has a sibling div using cypress?

Tags: cypress

Hi below is the html,

```
<div class="styledCard">
    <div class="cardHeader">
        <div class="headerLeft">
            <div class="title">title1</div>
            <div class="subtitle">subtitle1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

in here i want to check if title1 has subtitle1. i have like below

```
cy.textEqualsR('title', 'title1')
    .parentsR('styledCard')
    .containsR('div', 'subtitle1')
```

but the above fails. i am new to cypress. could someone help me out with this. thanks

Comment: What are these `textEqualsR`, `parentsR` and `containsR`. these doesn't look like valid cypress commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `parent()` and `contains()` you can do something like:

```
cy.contains('div.title', 'title1')
    .parent()     //yields.headerLeft
    .contains('div.subtitle', 'subtitle1')
```

Or, if you want to use `parents()`, you can use:

```
cy.contains('div.title', 'title1')
    .parents('div.styledCard')
    .contains('div.subtitle', 'subtitle1')
```